# Expurious newlines when setting buffer content in Neovim with Lua

Tags: lua, neovim, neovim-plugin

I am writing a Neovim plugin with Lua.  I am trying to set the contents of a buffer to the output of a shell command.  Here is my code:

```
local handle = io.popen("ls -1")
local result = handle:read("*a")
handle:close()

local output = {}
for s in result:gmatch("[^\r\n]*") do
    table.insert(output, s)
end

vim.api.nvim_buf_set_lines(buffer, 0, -1, false, output)
```

It works, but I get an extra newline at the end of each line, so the lines of `output` are separated by blank lines.

If instead I set the output myself, say to `output = {"a", "b", "c"}`, then it works as expected.

I have checked and there is no newline character at the end of the strings in `output`.  What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

I am using it like this and it works:

```
local inputDir = 'D:/Lua/'
local fileNames = {}
local filesString = io.popen('dir "'..inputDir..'" /b /a-d'):read("*a")
for fileName in filesString:gmatch("[^\r\n]+") do
    fileName = fileName:gsub("%.txt", "")
    table.insert(fileNames, fileName)
end
```

Comment: I noticed that, replacing * by + in my regular expression, so it is like yours, I get no newlines (but then the blank lines are ignored, which I don't want).  For some reason, when * is used, Lua is adding an empty string after each nonempty string.  But I checked that this is happening only in Neovim, not in the Lua interpreter on my terminal.  Any clues?

Comment: @Fernando try `:gmatch('([^\n]*)\n')` instead of `:gmatch("[^\r\n]+")`

Comment: If you want to catch carriage return as well, then `:gmatch('([^\r\n]*)\r?\n')` should work